# How to most efficiently store and access unique key combo?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app has two kind of objects, one is the `location` and the one is the `route` that goes from `locationA` to `locationB`.

`location` looks like this:

```
{
  "idLocationX" : {
    "address" : string
  }
}
```

`route` looks like this:

```
{
  "idLocationA": {
    "idLocationB": {
        "time": number,
        "distance": number
    }
  }
}
```

I decided on that structure for `route` because initially I thought, I could just go ahead and access `/routes/idLocationA/idLocationB` but that was obvious shortsighted.

I know that Firebase advices against nesting objects but I feel it's still the right and best way to quickly access the `route` while still keeping the overall data structure as lean as possible.

The alternative would now be to change the `route` structure to something like this:

```
{
    "idLocationA": true,
    "idLocationB": true,
    "start": "idLocationA",
    "end": "idLocationB",
    "time": number,
    "distance": number
}
```

That structure is obviously a lot leaner but I would need to do a different query and it feels less natural.

Can someone explain to me if there is a way to get data structure 1 for `route` (the current one, firstly mentioned above) to work in a Firebase database setting? I would basically need to get the path `/routes/{placeholder}/idLocationA/idLocationB` working.

Comment: What do you mean by placeholder? What and where is data structure 1?

Comment: I added some clarification. Data structure 1 is the current one I have. Placeholder stands for the `id` of the `route` that has the keys for the two idLocation as nested values.

Comment: Why do you need this? "idLocationA": true, "idLocationB": true

Comment: Can i ask what do you mean by route? I know what route means but in your case what do you actually use route for. Is it name of the street, combination of street or something else?

Comment: `"idLocationA": true, "idLocationB": true` makes indexing easier according to the Firebase manual, so I am not sure if it's necessary but maybe (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#fanout). A route is going from locationA to locationB and has the time it takes and the distance it is long as parameters. I will use it as input for an operational research problem (similar to job shop or vehicle routing).